# Variable used before being initialized error (Swift)

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I keep receiving an error/lint which reads `Variable 'self.item' used before being initialized`. This message only appears when I seemingly add a `@State` of type `Date` (see commented line below).

Variable `item` is a `CoreData` value that I'm attempting to update through a form. All of the other required data types (int, string, data, etc.) all work as expected.

I'm fairly confident that this is an issue which stems from my lack of experience with Swift or declarative-style languages in general, but I'm also wary that it could be a compiler issue as I seem to run into a few of those as well.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SelectionView: View {
    @State var item : Item
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @State private var name : String
    @State private var imageData : Data
    @State private var timestamp : Date // error only appears when this line is added
    
    init(item : Item) {
        self.item = item
        self._name = State(initialValue: item.name!)
        self._imageData = State(initialValue: item.imageData!)
        self._timestamp = State(initialValue: item.timestamp!)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form
            {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: imageData)!)
                Button(action: changeImage, label: { Text("Change image") })
                Button(action: save, label: { Text("Save") })
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }

    ...
```

Comment: You have declared the Date and trying to assign timestamp. Use same data time for @State var ```self._timestamp = State(initialValue: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: item.timestamp))```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Why does this not apply to name or imageData?

Comment: Do you really need the 3 other state variables? You could just use item. `$item.name`, `item.imageData`

Comment: Especially for Core Data I would use an `Observable` proxy class with  *from* and *to* methods in an extension of the `NSManagedObject` subclass. The benefit is a more convenient handling of the optionals and you don't need to insert a new object into the context if you also want to use the form for adding a new item.

Comment: @vadian would you be able to point me in the direction of some online resources which demonstrate this? I'm always looking to improve my code with relation to best possible practice, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do the following:

```
@State var item: Item

init(item: Item) {
    _item = State(initialValue: item)
}
```

You can access all of the things you may need:

- `item`
- `$item.name` (equivalent to when you had `$name`, same for other below)
- `$item.imageData`
- `$item.timestamp`

Also, if you don't need to pass anything else in, you can also get rid of the initializer because it is an inferred memberwise intializer.

Reason for the error you were having:

`self.item` doesn't exist yet. You set the `@State` with `_item`, and that will make the `item` and `$item` variables.

We can see this because seeing the definition of `State` shows the following:

```
public var wrappedValue: Value { get nonmutating set }  // Normal value

/* ... */

public var projectedValue: Binding<Value> { get }  // Binding value
```

So since you can't access `self.item` because `_item` hasn't been initialized yet, you get the error. That's why we set `_item` using `State(initialValue:)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have any idea why my solution is producing that specific error, though?

Comment: @Dan Added some explanation.

Comment: Often times in the initializer you will find that the order of initialization matters to the compiler. However, you should accept the above answer as it is the most correct and elegant solution. You should not declare 4 State variables where one will do.

Comment: Thank you. Excellent answer and it’ll help me to develop better applications in the future.

Comment: While you can do this `_item = ...` with property wrappers, it's considered an anti pattern if you initialise a `@State` variable in a SwiftUI View initialiser. This statement will have no effect when the associated storage for State for the "conceptual view" has been already initialised. Note, that the lifetime of struct View is not bound to the State, but to it's _identity_ - or the "conceptual view" with the same identity. The proper way to use "external" values is to pass them in as Bindings whose backing value usually come from an @ObservableObject or the like hosted by a parent view.